# Derive $\cos x(\ln x-x)^2$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have a doubt in deriving this function $\cos x(\ln x-x)^2$, deriving following the rules I obtain $$-\sin x(\ln x-x)^2+\cos x\left[2(\ln x-x)\left(\frac{1}{x}-1\right)\right]$$

Is it correct? I have doubts in particular in deriving $(\ln x-x)^2$. I must derive $(\ln x-x)^2 $ first and then $\ln x-x$?

Please help me I have too many doubts in deriving this simple exercises.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. And your understanding of the part of $(\ln x-x)^2$ is also fine.